# Exclude "hated buffers" from switch-to-buffer list

Tags: emacs

I have this in my .emacs:

```
(global-set-key "\M-s" 'switch-to-buffer)
```

And also:

```
(defvar crs-hated-buffers
  '("KILL" "*Compile-Log*" "*Buffer List*" "*Messages*" "*Occur*"
    "*Completions*" "*compilation*" "TAGS" "*scratch*" "*grep*"
    "source" "headers"))
(setq iswitchb-buffer-ignore (append '(
    "^ "
    "^\\*Buffer"
    "^\\*Completions\\*"
    "^\\*tramp"
    "^\\*Dired log\\*"
    "^\\*Quail Completions\\*"
    "^\\*Disabled Command\\*"
    "^TAGS"
    )
    crs-hated-buffers))
```

How do I exclude these hated buffers from the switch-to-buffer list?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like:

```
(global-set-key [?\M-s] 'my-switch-to-buffer)

(defun my-switch-to-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((completion-regexp-list '("\\`[^*]"
                                  "\\`\\([^T]\\|T\\($\\|[^A]\\|A\\($\\|[^G]\\|G\\($\\|[^S]\\|S.\\)\\)\\)\\).*")))
    (call-interactively 'switch-to-buffer)))
```

It probably deserves a feature-request via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Thanks stefan, I got this error:
Wrong type argument: commandp, my-switch-to-buffer

Comment: But with the (interactive) added I get this:
switch to buffer:(default ...etc).....there is no list of opened buffers that I choose from. I am saying that the behavior is completely now different from:
(global-set-key "\M-s" 'switch-to-buffer)

Comment: Ah, that's because you use iswitchb which remaps bindings to `switch-to-buffer` to `iswitchb-buffer`, but not bindings to `my-switch-to-buffer`.  Try to enable `icomplete-mode` which should give you the list you want.  Or otherwise, replace the `'switch-to-buffer` on the last line with `'iswitch-buffer`.

Comment: I get the dreaded:
Wrong type argument: commandp, iswitch-buffer

Comment: Ammari: Perhaps that was a typo for `iswitchb-buffer`? It's not an autoloaded function, so you *might* also need to `(require 'iswitchb)` first. (Or I could be completely wrong -- this is just a drive-by comment.)

Comment: Indeed, that was a typo.  Thanks @phils.  Note that iswitchb will be marked obsolete in 24.4, so you might like to give `icomplete-mode` (its replacement) a try.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look to ErgoEmacs' "switch to user buffer" functions: http://www.ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_next_prev_user_buffer.html

He excludes all internal buffers (the ones starting by *), which can be a problem if you're used to using *magit*, *shell* or even *grep* buffers.

«Emacs often generates a lot internal buffers that users are not interested in cycling thru. ⁖ {*scratch*, *Messages*, *shell*, *Shell Command Output*, *Occur*, *Completions*, *Apropos*, *info*, …}. You might define your own next-user-buffer that skips emacs's buffers, and you might define next-emacs-buffer that cycles thru just the emacs's buffers.
»

I myself find I don't need that kind of filter since I use ido to switch buffers.

Comment: Or [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)'s `helm-buffers-list` is also fantastic. Here is [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/KBmpXCJ.png?1).